# How to wipe the contents of a linux swap parition?

Tags: partition, swap

I have a parition /dev/sda3 of type "linux-swap" (as shown by gparted).

The partition is no longer in use and is also no longer an entry in /etc/fstab.

But I am concerned because there could still be sensitive information stored on this partition. Because it can contain everything that is stored in RAM normally. Like passwords or private E-Mails.

I want to wipe this partitions without destroying the file system.

I could overwrite the whole partition /dev/sda3 and then re-format it. But I will loose the uuid, partitions markings and label.

I think it must be possible to only wipe the contents?

I want to overwrite everything stored on this partitions so it's really gone (overwritten with zeroes).

How to do that?

Comment: You also say, "_I could overwrite the whole partition /dev/sda3 and then re-format it. But I will loose the uuid, partitions markings and label._" - why is that a problem? It's a swap partition. You can re-add the same UUID and Label from `mkswap` later, if you really want to.

Comment: Note that even overwriting with zeros still has some potential for recovering data. Use random data for the overwriting instead.

Comment: @FelixJN, changing to random data doesn't help for COW or journaling filesystems (which aren't the case here) or for relocation or wear-levelling on the device, though.

Comment: if the swap partition is "no longer in use" and "no longer an entry in /etc/fstab", why are you be worried about conserving the UUID or label? Even if you mean to reuse the partition as a new swap device, you'll need to add a new entry for it in fstab and enter those again, new or old ones. If you're planning to put the whole drive to a new use, you should probably worry about any remains of files in other partitions too, and wiping individual files from a filesystem may be much harder. Unless you just wipe the whole drive and copy back the data that needs to be there

Comment: I might want to use the partition in the future again. That's why I only wanted to clear the data stored on it. On a normal file system you can use **ls** to list the contents, use **rm** and **dd** to delete data. I thought there might be equivalent commands for swap devices. But if someone creates an answer telling that this is not possible and the only way is to format the partition then I will accept it as "solved the problem".

Comment: Oh I see your concern. Swap isn't a filesystem, so normal filesystem operations don't necessarily apply.

Comment: @roaima Of course it's not. But it must be structured somehow. I think the data is not random bits.

Comment: @FelixJN Do you have a reference on using something other than zeros for wiping disks? NIST 800-88 disagrees with you.

Comment: @somega I've updated my answer to try and address these concerns

Comment: @doneal24 looks like [data remanence](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Securely_wipe_disk#Data_remanence) due to residual magnetism is way outdated by now. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Disks contain partitions.  Labels are part of a filesystem or swap on a partition.  UUIDs are on both disks and partitions.

If you wipe `/dev/sda3` you wipe only the partition, not the disk, not the partition table, and not labels or UUIDs of other partitions.   I don't know why you'd be concerned about wiping the UUID and label, they don't contain any critical information, and you could always record them (the UUID is just a number, the label just a string) and put them back if/when you reformat sda3 or just use the new UUID it would get if you don't specify one.

When you say it's not in use, I assume it doesn't show up in `/proc/swaps`.

Answer (score 3):

All the commands here must be run as root (`sudo -s`).

In your case the swap partition is /dev/sda3. You can confirm that it's not in use by listing the active swap partitions with `swapon -s`. In this example from one of my own systems it lists only `/var/swap`: a file (rather than a device) containing swap data. There is no other file or device listed.

```
swapon -s
Filename    Type   Size     Used   Priority
/var/swap   file   102396   880    -1
```

At this point I can say that `/dev/sda3` was definitely not in use as a swap partition. Erase it in the usual manner by writing zeros:

```
cat /dev/zero >/dev/sda3
```

There is absolutely no need whatsoever to overwrite with random data. Zeros are just fine<sup>*</sup>.

(As an aside, unlike a filesystem where individual files and directories can be viewed and manipulated by commands such as `ls`, `cat`, `cp` and so on, the swap partition should be considered an *opaque object*. That is, the contents and its structure are not accessible and should be considered as a single entity. This means that there is no accessible mechanism for removing individual items from the swap space, and so we have to erase it completely and then choose to recreate it.)

If you previously recorded the UUID and Label you can now recreate the swap with those values:

```
mkswap --uuid {uuid} --label {label} /dev/sda3
```

Both `--uuid` and `--label` are optional, so by omitting both you can recreate the swap partition with default generated values.

* References:

1. [How many times must you overwrite a hard disk for complete data erasure?](https://www.blancco.com/resources/blog-many-overwriting-rounds-required-erase-hard-disk/), Aug 2019
2. [NIST 800-88, Rev. 1 (PDF)](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-88r1.pdf), Dec 2014
3. [Overwriting Hard Drive Data: The Great Wiping Controversy](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221160815_Overwriting_Hard_Drive_Data_The_Great_Wiping_Controversy), Dec 2008